# Play Store does not allow me to test my app

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have been trying to test in-app-billing by uploading an apk to the Google Developer Console and trying to make a purchase.
I keep getting the message The Play Store Application on your device is outdated and does not support this purchase.
Yet I am using version 3.9 of Google Play.
My device is an HTC Wildfire using Android 2.2.1
I am able to download apps as normal.

Comment: which InAppPurchase version you have implemented in your code ?

Comment: You should be using iap-v3.

Comment: then it will not work, you need to implement InAppBiling version 2.

Comment: I was assuming it was version 3 because I got the necessary files from the samples provided by Google - the Trivial Drive Sample.

Comment: I shall try to get hold of version 2

Comment: Actually, how can I find out what version I am using? It isn't mentioned in the 9 utility files given in Trivial Drive Sample. Unless it could be the phrase "Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0". The only source I can find for these files is the Trivial Drive Sample provided under "extras" in the sdk. There is no choice of versions.

Comment: I am pretty sure I am using version 3. I thought it was supposed to work with Froyo?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have given up on this and decided not to implement inapp billing

Answer (score 0):

Youu need to set min sdk 8 and check all your permissions in manifest.